# Timer to start pause and resume

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, prototype

I'm using this Plugin for Timer https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles
and is best for what I need. But always is here but :D

I want to make this timer to work better like when i click pause to pause not to pause only animation of circles also the time to stop. So here is my code

```js
$(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles({
    "animation": "smooth",
    "bg_width": 1.2,
    "fg_width": 0.1,
    "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
    "start": false,
    "time": {
        "Days": {
            "text": "Days",
            "color": "#FFCC66",
            "show": true
        },
        "Hours": {
            "text": "Hours",
            "color": "#99CCFF",
            "show": true
        },
        "Minutes": {
            "text": "Minutes",
            "color": "#BBFFBB",
            "show": true
        },
        "Seconds": {
            "text": "Seconds",
            "color": "#FF9999",
            "show": true
        }
    }
});

$(".start").click(function () {
    $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().start();
});
$(".stop").click(function () {
    $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().stop();
});
$(".restart").click(function () {
    $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().restart();
});
```

```css
/**
 * This element is created inside your target element
 * It is used so that your own element will not need to be altered
 **/
.time_circles {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/**
 * This is all the elements used to house all text used
 * in time circles
 **/
.time_circles > div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

/**
 * Titles (Days, Hours, etc)
 **/
.time_circles > div > h4 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
}

/**
 * Time numbers, ie: 12
 **/
.time_circles > div > span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/TimeCircles.js"></script>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="example stopwatch" data-date="2016-07-20 00:00:00" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            
        
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-small start">Start</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small stop">Stop</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-small restart">Restart</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes it is working as expected....

Comment: ex.
2h 20min 20sec
clicking pause at 2h 50min 10sec
clicking resume after 20min it need to be same as prevision 2h 50min 10sec not to show me 3h 10min 20sec

is not working as I want try it like make pause for 30sec and after click start

Comment: yes I see the issue now.

Answer (score 3):

Do you realize its a Timer and **Not a Stop Watch** it counts down/up to some given time.

So in this example you have give the date time as `2016-07-20 00:00:00` so when ever the timer runs it shows how much time has passed to the above date time. This means no matter when you run the timer it will calculate the amount of time passed from the initial given date time and display it.

Taken from the plugin documentation

> TimeCircles is a jQuery plugin that provides a nice looking way to
>   either count down towards a certain time, or to count up from a
>   certain time. The goal for TimeCircles is to provide a simple yet
>   dynamic tool that makes it very easy to provide visitors an attractive
>   countdown or timer.

So what you are asking for is a **Stop Watch**

**Edit 1: (Thanks to your comment about data-timer)** In order to make it as a stopwath you need to use `data-timer="0"` instead of `data-date="2016-07-20 00:00:00"`

Below is a working demo

```js
$(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles({
  "animation": "smooth",
  "bg_width": 1.2,
  "fg_width": 0.1,
  "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
  "start": false,
  "time": {
    "Days": {
      "text": "Days",
      "color": "#FFCC66",
      "show": true
    },
    "Hours": {
      "text": "Hours",
      "color": "#99CCFF",
      "show": true
    },
    "Minutes": {
      "text": "Minutes",
      "color": "#BBFFBB",
      "show": true
    },
    "Seconds": {
      "text": "Seconds",
      "color": "#FF9999",
      "show": true
    }
  }
});

$(".start").click(function() {
  $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().start();
});
$(".stop").click(function() {
  $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().stop();
});
$(".restart").click(function() {
  $(".example.stopwatch").TimeCircles().restart();
});
```

```css
/**
 * This element is created inside your target element
 * It is used so that your own element will not need to be altered
 **/

.time_circles {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/**
 * This is all the elements used to house all text used
 * in time circles
 **/

.time_circles > div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
/**
 * Titles (Days, Hours, etc)
 **/

.time_circles > div > h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
}
/**
 * Time numbers, ie: 12
 **/

.time_circles > div > span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
  font-size: 300%;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="example stopwatch" data-timer="0" style="width: 100%;"></div>


  <button class="btn btn-success btn-small start">Start</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small stop">Stop</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-small restart">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I know. So can you provide similar to this something that will work for my proposes ? thanks

Comment: @ViktorD I can think of a work around for this. I will update my answer.

Comment: it will be great if u have some implementation for this. thank u

Comment: So i find solution for this if i use data-timer="1200" it will work but i need to make change to script to timer go up with numbers not down. also animation need to go up no reverse. i think u understand me what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @ViktorD thanks for the `data-timer` clue. That does the trick when set to 0

Comment: but what will happend when we start time from ex data-timer="1500" timer need to start from that period at to count up.

Comment: @ViktorD The plugin is like if you give zero it starts to count up... else if you give some number then it will start counting down untill it reaches 0

Comment: yes I know that. So I'm asking how is possible to adapt this plugin to count up if we give some value.